# How do I extract unique id along with the whole dataframe using R?

Tags: r

How do I reach from left to right using R in the screenshot? If I use `unique(mydata$id)`, it only gives a list of unique ids instead of the whole data frame. Is there another function for this?

Here is the demonstration of my data frame:

[image]

Comment: `unique(mydata)` will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

distinct(mydata)
# or, other way of writing it:
mydata %>% distinct()
```